# why R shows "Error in if (cc < ep) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r

There is no logic mistake in the fillowing code, because it can run one line by one line, however, R keeps showing "Error in if (cc < ep) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
" when I source the code. I am totally confused, is there anyone who can help findding the reason?

```
iteration =function(f, x_0, ep=1e-5, it_max=1000){
  index <- 0
  k <- 1 # k
  while(k <= it_max){
    x_1 <- f(x_0)
    cc <- abs(x_1 - x_0)
    x_0 <- x_1
    if(cc < ep) {
      index <- 1
      break
    }
    k <- k + 1
  }
list(root=x_0, it_num=k, index=index)
}



funs <- function(x) {(1 - 4 * x)^(1/3)}
iteration(funs, 0.2)
```

Comment: Looks like you are calling your function with only one argument and it’s definition implies it would need at least two. The missingness of x_1 propagates to  cc

Comment: The `funs` function returns `NaN` if the value of `x` is greater than 0.25. This happens the second time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and any sugesstion on how to fix it?

Comment: Use `funs <- function(x) sign(1 - 4 * x) * abs(1 - 4 * x)^(1/3)` instead. Why? Try `(-1)^(1/3)` to see the same problem. If the principal root is a complex number you will have *real* errors.

Comment: One fix is simply to ensure the cube root is never attempted on a negative number by using `abs` but this may not be what your requirement is.

Comment: Any reason these comments could not have been entered as answers?